# What is the purpose of this symbol used with curl

Tags: curl

```
 CURL -XPOST 'LOCALHOST:9200' --data-binary @<(for docs in ./)............
```

I have tried to search for the < symbol everywhere but cannot find it in any documentation.

I'm assuming it allows you to code some logic to process the data prior to it being sent across but where do I find more information on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` is a redirection of `stdin`: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

It's not a `curl` thing per se, it's about the shell.

This may bring you to another question: the `()` wraps a subshell which is going produce the output that gets redirected to the `stdin` of the `curl` command.